# Как поменять имя дистрибутива в anaconde

Tags: linux, дистрибутив, anaconda

У меня есть задача - создать дистрибутив на основе Scientific Linux. Я уже включил свои пакеты, собрал пакеты с названием линукса и бутскрином, но при установке и создания записи в загрузчике GRUB остается старое название.

Как поменять название ОС в инсталяторе?

Answer (score 1):

судя по содержимому файлов `/usr/sbin/new-kernel-pkg` (из пакета `grubby`) и `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` (из пакета `grub2-tools`) для дистрибутива *scientific linux* версии 7.2, информация (в первую очередь) черпается из файла `/etc/os-release`.

насколько я вижу, этот файл входит как минимум в пакет `sl-release` и (для версии 7.2) имеет следующее содержание:

```
NAME="Scientific Linux"
VERSION="7.2 (Nitrogen)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.2"
PRETTY_NAME="Scientific Linux 7.2 (Nitrogen)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:scientificlinux:scientificlinux:7.2:GA"
HOME_URL="http://www.scientificlinux.org//"
BUG_REPORT_URL="mailto:scientific-linux-devel@listserv.fnal.gov"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Scientific Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.2
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Scientific Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.2"
```

вот этот пакет, вероятно, вам и стоит пересобрать, изменив требующуюся информацию.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь :) Кроме пакета sl-release нужно еще редактировать .buildstamp из образа isolinux/initrd.img `201411051529.x86_64
Scientific Linux
6.6
FINAL=YES
Send email to scientific-linux-devel@fnal.gov
`

Comment: @Xerzing, возможно. правда, не совсем понятно, при чём тут isolinux, раз в вопросе речь про grub.